# How to customize vertical scrollbar default direction on Tomahawk inputTextarea?

Tags: jsf, scroll, textarea, tomahawk

I got the following jsf-code:

```
<t:inputTextarea id="exportStatusMessage" cols="85" rows="10" readonly="true" value="#{ExportController.statusMessages}"/>
```

Is it possible to tell the inputTextarea to scroll to bottom after rendering the page? 
Maybe you know Eclipse-Console, I want to achieve this behaviour. Maybe there is a JavaScript-snippet or JSF-attribute which handles this issue - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed just use JavaScript for this.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <t:inputTextarea id="exportStatusMessage" ... />
</h:form>

<script>
    var textarea = document.getElementById("form:exportStatusMessage");
    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
</script>
```

Note that the script must be executed after the HTML `<textarea>` representation is been added to the HTML DOM tree. So if you intend to put the script in its own `.js` file, make sure that it's executed during page onload, or is been referenced in end of `<body>`.